# Avoid Round Up when converting float to varchar

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal, rounding

I got problem when converting float to varchar and it's alway round up. for the example

if I convert :
0.65 it became 1, but I only want 0
1.55 it became 2, but I only want 1

here's my code :

```
  Declare @Dt1 dateTime Set @Dt1 = '2014-03-05 10:15:53.110'
  Declare @Dt2 dateTime Set @Dt2 = getdate()

  Select str((Cast((@Dt2 - @Dt1) as Float) * 24.0)) as hours1 , 
  str(Cast((@Dt2 - @Dt1) as Float) * 24.0*60.0)%60 as minutes1
```

is it possible to avoid rounding up when converting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `ROUND` method? However the following SQL may fit your requirement:

```
Select str((Cast((@Dt2 - @Dt1) as Float) * 24.0)) as hours1 , 
  str(ROUND(Cast((@Dt2 - @Dt1) as Float) * 24.0*60.0, 0, 1))%60 as minutes1
```

Comment: wow you saved my day, just know about Round in SQL. I'll look for refrence to know more, and yes the code you give is Exact like what I want.

Comment: Here is the official documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx